# PHP/HTML/JS: How is this HTML form processed?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

SETUP:

I was reverse engineering the back end of this page for fun and practice when I came along something that I don't quite understand:

When register is clicked there is an initial input validation by AttemptRegister() in /js/login.js which checks to see that none of the fields are empty, contain the default values, and makes sure the passwords match.

```
function AttemptRegister() {
 // Simple validation of input fields first
 var status=document.getElementById("regstatus");
 status.style.color='#000000';
 status.value = "";

 var username = document.getElementById("username");
 var email = document.getElementById("email");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword");

if(""==username.value || "user name"==username.value) {
    status.style.color='#C00000';
    status.value = "Invalid user name";
    username.selected = true;
    return;
}
if(""==email.value || "email" == email.value) {
    status.style.color='#C00000';
    status.value = "Invalid email address";
    email.selected = true;
    return;
}
if(""==password.value || "password" == password.value) {
    status.style.color='#C00000';
    status.value = "Must provide password";
    password.selected = true;
    return;
}
if(password.value!=confirmPassword.value ) {
    status.style.color='#C00000';
    status.value = "Passwords do not match";
    password.selected = true;
    return;
}

// We open the thankyou page for registering, as that's where the actual registration occurs on the POST variables.  If they fail, we'll get kicked back here
status.value = "Submitting...";
//window.location.href='thankyou_reg.html';

// Submit with hidden form
var form = document.getElementById("submitEmail").form;
document.getElementById("submitEmail").value = email.value;
document.getElementById("submitUsername").value = username.value;
document.getElementById("submitPassword").value = password.value;
form.submit();
```

}

It sets the "regstatus" field in the html to "Submitting..." and fills out the below hidden html form and submits it **to thankyou_reg.html?**

```
<form action="thankyou_reg.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitEmail" id="submitEmail" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitUsername" id="submitUsername" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitPassword" id="submitPassword" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="registerSubmit" id="registerSubmit" value="true"/>
</form>
```

This is where I am confused, how can the form data be processed by a flat .html page?  It does a secondary validation check to ensure the username and password are long enough, that the email is of the proper format and also queries a database to make sure this email or username are not already in use.  If it fails any of these it bounces back to the index.html page and updates the "regstatus" input field again with an error message.

QUESTION:

What am I missing here?  Is there a way in PHP or server settings to divert a form action, "thankyou_reg.html" in this case, and redirect it to a php page?  Then load either "thankyou_reg.html" on success or back to "index.html" on failure, WITH javascript that will execute the value change of "regstatus"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .htaccess file, it is possible to change the settings to run PHP code in a file with a .html extension. The website you were using probably changed it to run PHP.

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: Ah ha, that must be it.  I'm going to check that out.  Thank you!

Comment: For anyone else using WAMP like myself you do this by going to wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\conf\httpd.conf and adding the line

    `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

near the other AddType application/x-httpd-php entries

Answer (score 0):

There are ways with Apache and other servers to specify what application should be loaded for specific file extensions. For example, the `.php` extension signifies that PHP should be loaded and should handle the request. My idea is that the `.html` extension is actually being processed by a server application (could be PHP), but they could have done that to obfuscate what is doing the processing under the hood.

There could be rewrite rules in place that map `thankyou_reg.html` to a php page. For example, it might be nice to map it to something like `index.php?forward=thankyou_reg.html` which gives you prettier user facing url's.

Also `thankyou_reg.html` could be a directory with an `index.php` file inside.

But really anything could be happening under the hood.